# how to increase the vibration of pressing home button

Tags: settings, vibration

I have a Nexus 5.

My phone vibrates when I press the home button. The problem is the vibration is a little weaker than I would like. Is there a way to increae the vibratoin intensity of that feature?

I've come across this app but it's doesn't work well on my phone. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dunnow.software.vibrationTuner

Is there a setting in Android like this?

Comment: Have you rooted your device? Would you be looking for a solution that is non-root? Are you still using the stock version of Android or have you installed any custom ROM?

Comment: No, i have not rooted my phone. I'd prefer to find a non-rooted if that is possible. I'm still using the stock version of Android. I have not installed any custom ROM.

Comment: I doubt you will ever find any program that doesn't require root access. However I am really curious about this.